# How to make modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp persist a reboot on CentOS 7 and firewalld?

Tags: centos, modprobe, firewalld, proftpd

I'm stumped. I've seen the [related questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447617/how-to-make-modprobe-ip-conntrack-ftp-persist-a-reboot) about editing `/etc/sysconfig/iptables-config`, but I'm running CentOS 7 (and webmin/virtualmin), which uses firewalld instead of iptables.

How do I get `modprobe nf_conntrack_ftp` to persist after a reboot? I tried setting up a cron on reboot to issue the command, but that didn't work (and is probably the wrong way to go about it anyway).

Right now after every reboot I have to login and type in the command manually in order to get FTP connections to work correctly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In /etc/modules-load.d, add a file {filename}.conf. That file should have the following contents:

```
nf_conntrack_ftp
```

Do the following for more info:

```
man modules-load.d
```

Here's the doc for RHEL7:
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/sec-Persistent_Module_Loading.html